# Control AKSequencer with MPRemoteCommandCenter

Tags: audiokit, mpremotecommandcenter

Is it possible to control `AKSequencer` with `MPRemoteCommandCenter` and if so what's the setup required for that? I had no issues with displaying and managing playback info using default `AVAudioPlayer` but it doesn't work with `AudioKit`.

`MPRemoteCommandCenter` never appears. Ideally I want to be able to call `sequencer.play()`, `sequencer.stop()` on corresponding events from the lock screen but I can't even get controls showing on the lock screen.

I've tried a dirty hack like playing an audio file with basic `AVAudioPlayer` in parallel with `sequencer` and the sound is working just fine but control center is not there.

If I don't call `play` method on my sequencer and just leave `AVAudioPlayer` to play as usual, command center works as expected.